# how to check if the the user logged in?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento2.3

i try to check if the user logged in , and i logged in but it returns the message says that i'm not logged in why ?? i tried 2 methods

```
<?php

namespace Main\Store\Block;

use Magento\Customer\Model\Session;

class wishlist extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    protected $customerSession;

    /**
     * 
     * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        Session $customerSession,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->customerSession = $customerSession;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }



    public function addedToWishlist()
    {
        if ($this->customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {
            echo '<h2> Yes he is loggin';
        } else {
            echo '<h2> No he is not loggin';
        }


        // $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        // $customerSession = $objectManager->get('Magento\Customer\Model\Session');
        // if ($customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {
        //     echo '<h2> Yes he is loggin';
        // } else {
        //     echo '<h2> No he is not loggin';
        // }
    }
}
```

and this phml file

```
<?php

$wishlist = $block->getLayout()->createBlock('Main\Store\Block\wishlist');
$wishlist->addedToWishlist();
```

[image]

Comment: your code seems correct, alternatively you can try factory method as well describe in this blog: https://blog.chapagain.com.np/magento-2-check-if-customer-is-logged-in-or-not/

Answer (score 1):

The **Magento\Customer\Model\Session** class cannot be used to determine if a customer is logged in or not when the page cache (full_page) is enabled.

By default, Magento has already added a flag to check whether a customer is logged in or not in the cache context. This flag is added to
`\Magento\Customer\Model\App\Action\ContextPlugin::beforeExecute` method:

```
/**
 * Set customer group and customer session id to HTTP context
 *
 * @param ActionInterface $subject
 * @return void
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.UnusedFormalParameter)
 */
public function beforeExecute(ActionInterface $subject)
{
    $this->httpContext->setValue(
        Context::CONTEXT_GROUP,
        $this->customerSession->getCustomerGroupId(),
        GroupManagement::NOT_LOGGED_IN_ID
    );
    $this->httpContext->setValue(
        Context::CONTEXT_AUTH,
        $this->customerSession->isLoggedIn(),
        false
    );
}
```

So, you can inject the `Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context` class in your class to get that flag value. The code should look similar to this:

```
use Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context as HttpContext;
//...
public function __construct(
    //...
    HttpContext $httpContext
) {
    //...
    $this->httpContext = $httpContext;
}

private function isCustomerLoggedIn()
{
    return (bool)$this->httpContext->getValue(CustomerContext::CONTEXT_AUTH);
}
```

Apply to your code, it should look like the following code:

```
use Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context as HttpContext;
//...
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        HttpContext $httpContext,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->httpContext = $httpContext;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }



    public function addedToWishlist()
    {
        if ((bool)$this->httpContext->getValue(CustomerContext::CONTEXT_AUTH)) {
            echo '<h2> Yes he is loggin';
        } else {
            echo '<h2> No he is not loggin';
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a github issue for your problem. Its because of cache you got null in Magento\Customer\Model\Session

```
https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/3294
```

Its safe to use factory methods. If you use factory you can get customer is logged in or not . You can use like below.

```
use Magento\Customer\Model\SessionFactory;

public function __construct(
        SessionFactory $customerFactory
    ) {
        $this->customerFactory = $customerFactory;
    }
```

In your method you can use

```
 $customer = $this->customerFactory->create();
        if ($customer->isLoggedIn()) {
//your code.
    }
```

Please upvote if its helpful